# Diff -b and -w difference

Tags: linux, command-line, diff

From the `diff` manpage:

```
-b, --ignore-space-change
      ignore changes in the amount of white space

-w, --ignore-all-space
      ignore all white space
```

From this, I infer that the difference between the `-b` and `-w` options must be that `-b` is sensitive to the *type* of whitespace (tabs vs. spaces). However, that does not seem to be the case:

```
$ diff 1.txt 2.txt 
1,3c1,3
<     Four spaces, changed to one tab
<         Eight Spaces, changed to two tabs
<     Four spaces, changed to two spaces
---
>       Four spaces, changed to one tab
>               Eight Spaces, changed to two tabs
>   Four spaces, changed to two spaces
$ diff -b 1.txt 2.txt 
$ diff -w 1.txt 2.txt 
$
```

So, what is the difference between the `-b` and `-w` options? Tested with diffutils 3.2 on Kubuntu Linux 13.04.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The man page isn't very clear on that point, but the info page elaborates:

> **1.2 Suppressing Differences in Blank and Tab Spacing**
>
> The `--ignore-tab-expansion` (`-E`) option ignores the distinction
>   between tabs and spaces on input.  A tab is considered to be
>   equivalent to the number of spaces to the next tab stop (*note
>   Tabs::).
>
> The `--ignore-trailing-space` (`-Z`) option ignores white space at
>   line end.
>
> The `--ignore-space-change` (`-b`) option is stronger than `-E` and
>   `-Z` combined.  It ignores white space at line end, and considers all
>   other sequences of one or more white space characters within a line to
>   be equivalent.  With this option, `diff` considers the following two
>   lines to be equivalent, where `$` denotes the line end:
>
> ```
>  Here lyeth  muche rychnesse  in lytell space.   -- John Heywood$
>  Here lyeth muche rychnesse in lytell space. -- John Heywood   $
> ```
>
> The `--ignore-all-space` (`-w`) option is stronger still.  It
>   ignores differences even if one line has white space where the other
>   line has none.  "White space" characters include tab, vertical tab,
>   form feed, carriage return, and space; some locales may define
>   additional characters to be white space.  With this option, `diff`
>   considers the following two lines to be equivalent, where `$` denotes
>   the line end and `^M` denotes a carriage return:
>
> ```
>  Here lyeth  muche  rychnesse in lytell space.--  John Heywood$
>    He relyeth much erychnes  seinly tells pace.  --John Heywood   ^M$
> ```
>
> For many other programs newline is also a white space character,
>   but `diff` is a line-oriented program and a newline character always
>   ends a line.  Hence the `-w` or `--ignore-all-space` option does not
>   ignore newline-related changes; it ignores only other white space
>   changes.

Comment: I was surprised that none of those (not even -w / --ignore-all-space) ignores newlines.  So even with -w, you may still need --ignore-blank-lines

Comment: Re: "-w or --ignore-all-space option does not ignore newline-related changes"  

So -w ignores all whitespace, except for the whitespace it doesn't ignore.  Ok, got it.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like it is spaces between words maybe more but this is my result:

```
diff 1.txt 2.txt 
1,2c1,2
< test
< next next
---
> te  st     
> next  next


diff -b 1.txt 2.txt 
1c1
< test
---
> te  st
```

results from -w is nothing.